# How to approach the problem

Tags: problem-solving

x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + 1 = 4xyz
No. Of triplets of real numbers satisfying the eqn?
I'm not able to figure how to approach this problem.

Comment: @user222031 Strictly speaking the question is asking for how to approach the problem, rather than what the solution is. Not sure if this is enough of a difference, though.

Comment: @eyeballfrog That question also asks how to approach the problem